# Finding the shortest route from current location to the locations marked on a map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-directions-api

I have mapped my current location and also 4 other locations on my map.Is it possible the mark the route which is closest to the current location(1),then from that(1) to the next closest(2) position,then so on(3).!!Finally i should have the route from my current location marker via all the location in between(markers) till the last marker!!
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem

Comment: So what have you done so far?  Since you have tagged google-maps, you should look at Google Directions API. You can certainly do what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks @SivaKanesh,Iv worked with Google Directions and now m able to mark the route between two location,but i need mark a route for all the locations(i.e,4 locations starting from current)

Comment: Please check this post http://vesuviusblog.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/finding-the-shortest-path-from-current-location-to-the-locations-marked-on-the-map/

Answer (score 1):

You are going to have to use separate instance of `DirectionsService` object to make your directions request for each destination and then set that to the map using the same instance of the `DirectionsRenderer` object.

Take a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2SL8Z/5/)

There are three separate directions in this example.  Just make the start the same location.

Comment: Can you give the android code plz(the code in JSFiddle is in javascript)!!

Comment: If its possible, can anyone update this code http://vesuviusblog.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/finding-the-shortest-path-from-current-location-to-the-locations-marked-on-the-map/